# Best practice to represent Object tree in Drools

Tags: drools

We are working on a monitoring application in which we follow the processing of a task in a set of applications.
Each application task processing is designed as ChainStep, the whole task process is designed as Chain.
Chain contains a tree of ChainSteps, each ChainStep may be parent of others.
We have a set of drools rules matching our needs but we have some performance issues (we may have easily up to 50k objects in session).
We are looking for best practices to improve drools performances.

Currently we represent Chains and ChainSteps as flat objects, each object has Id (GUID), we frequently have rule with conditions such as:

```
rule "Chain_App1_LinkToParent"
when $app1Step:App1ChainStep(!HasParent )
     $app2Step:App2ChainStep($app2Step.ChainId == $app1Step.ChainId)
then
modify($app1Step) {
        setParent($app2Step.getId()),
        setHasParent(true)
   }
end
```

(App1ChainStep and App2ChainStep both extends ChainStep type)

We tried to use unification but rules processing seems slower

```
when $app1Step:App1ChainStep(!HasParent, $Id:=ChainId )
     $app2Step:App2ChainStep($Id:=ChainId)
```

We are working now on a non flat representation, but we encounter problems on rules triggering on object modifications.
For example:

```
rule "SetChainCollectable"
when
    $chain:Chain(!Collectable )
    not ( exists( $chainStep:ChainStep( !Collectable)  from $chain.Steps))
then
    modify($chain){
        setCollectable(true)
    }
end
```

seems not triggered on ChainStep modification of Collectable flag.

We would like to sure to obtain a better result before to finnish to migrate our rules.

What would be the more efficient way to represent object tree in Drools ?

Answer (score 0):

For designing an efficient fact representation all use cases and their frequencies must be taken into account. (What you've let out in your question is far from the mark.) So I can only point out a few oddities I've observed:

1. Maintaining a `parent` and a `hasParent` could be simplified. Most of the time, IDs have a null value, `NULL` or `0` etc. Perhaps you should object references rather than ID values.
2. Unification isn't useful for the rule pattern you have there.
3. `not( exists() )` is redundant - `not()` is the negative existence quantifier all by itself. (Drools discards the `exists` in this situation.)
4. `from <expression>` iterating over some POJOs (not facts) in a collection creates what I call "temporary facts", which, as facts, are limited to the context of the condition where the from clause is written. Thus, the Engine is not aware of any modification of a `ChainStep` object. ChainStep objects must be facts if you expect rules to react to their modification.

Basically, representing graphs by nodes as facts and with references to neighbours - up or down, or up and down, perhaps even including siblings, if it is a tree - is the way to go. But I'm not going to say more - see the initial paragraph.

Comment: You are right, and i understand, when you say you have not enough information to provide us more optimization tips on our exact use case.
We will work on a solution using object instead of ids in our tree representation.

We would like to have something more objective to qualify (quantify) the performance of rules triggering in our different implementation options.
Does it exist in Drools something equivalent of the SQL world "execution path" where we have things like 'IndexSeek' 'IndexScan' 'TableScan' to understand operations executed during request resolution ?

Comment: The organization of the network (Rete or the 6.x Phreaky) is quite different from anything a RDBS might need for its queries. I think that the amount of objects allocated in the dynamically evolving network might be one measure.  - Much CPU time can be wasted by poor rules, which are more complex than the ones you have shown. - Timing various scenarios may indicate bottlenecks, but garbage collection may distort such readings.